# Using stored procedure to export data to excel in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, excel, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL database using Workbench , Is there anyway that i can export my all the data in a table to an excel sheet when i run a stored procedure.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE statement can help you to export MySQL table data to Microsoft Excel. It’s used when anyone wants to direct query output to a file.

This file can then be opened by MS Excel, or imported into another database like Microsoft Access, Oracle, or any other delimitation supporting software.

Take an example, it seems working for me with Windows

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "C:\\export_table_data_excel.xls" 
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM database_name.table_name;
```

The export_table_data_excel.xls will be created at C drive. If the target file path is omitted, then this file will be created at MySQL data directory.

Use this code to your stored procedure

Comment: I tried the query , it is putting the data in the excel sheet, but is there any way i can put it in the exact columns in excel corresponding to the mysql table ??

Comment: yes, just remove * and add your needed column names and thats it.